# Two Hard-coded Arrays OF DIFFERENT SIZES into One 2-Dimensional Vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

---

I realize that if I want "valArray" to populate to the right of "COLUMN 0,0" I should put "[j][1]", however, I keep getting an error when I do that.
OUTPUT:----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
55 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------THIS IS ROW 1------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 10 10 11 ----THIS IS ROW 2-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
77 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------THIS IS ROW 3------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
88 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------THIS IS ROW 4-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please advise how to populate correctly, thanks.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()          
{   

 int typeArray[4] = {55,66,77,88};
 int valArray[13] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,11};

 // for vector: 4 = LENGTH or NUMBER of ROWS; 13 = WIDTH or NUMBER of COLUMNS;
 //  0 = VALUE all cells are initialized to
  vector< vector <int> > myVector(4, vector<int> (13,0));

 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {         
     myVector[i][0] = typeArray[i];

     for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
      {
         myVector[1][J] = valArray[j];

         }
     }      

   // print vector to screen with 2 ROWS, 3 COLUMNS
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      {         
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
         { 
          cout << myVector[i][j] << ' ';
          }         
          cout << '\n';
      } 

    system("Pause");
    return 0; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is because you are not assigning any values to myVector.

Assuming typeArray and valArray are of the same length and you want to place each in a column, try something like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(typeArray)/sizeof(int); j++)
{
     myVector[j][0] = typeArray[j];
     myVector[j][1] = valArray[j];
}
```

Comment: The order of your indices for the myVector is wrong. Should be [j][0] or [j][1]. The inner vector is the one with a size of two.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg Thanks didn't notice that

Comment: Ethan, Thank you for the fast response!  I have to get up early tomorrow, so I need to look at this tomorrow.  I am so excited to get assistance on this.  I'll get back with you Tuesday, tx again!

Comment: Hi Ethan,  I am still kind of new to this forum, and could only post revised code in my orignal section by editing it.  Is there a better way?  Anyway, if you are available, would you please take a look at the code with my new questions.  I'm not sure why the questions are so large in font, however, it's the content, right?  TX!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the loops should be until `sizeof(typeArray)/sizeof(typeArray[0])` instead of `sizeof(typeArray)`. Sizeof simply gives you the size of the array in bytes. You need to divide that by the size of each element in order to get the number of elements.

As for how to combine the arrays, I think you have the right idea with the for loop, and simply manually assigning the values.

example psuedo code:

```
for each element in typeArray
myVector[i][0] = typeArray[i];
myVector[i][1] = valArray[i];
```

Comment: Ethan, Thank you for the additional info.  I have to get up early tomorrow, so I need to look at this tomorrow.  I will be on it full force and getting back with you, C U then.